# the question of $F_{X Y}(x,y) =P[X≤x,Y≤y]$

Tags: probability

I know $F_{XY}(x,y)$=$P[X \le x,Y \le y]$,but is $F_{XY}(-\infty,2)$ equal to zero?I wonder can it be calculated and be written as the form of $f_{XY}(x,y)$

This question also let me confused,is $F_{XY}(-\infty,\infty)$=$1$?Well, i know the sum of joint CDF must be equal to  $1$,but according to $F_{XY}(x,y)$=$P[X \le x,Y \le y]$,it become

$F_{XY}(-\infty,\infty)$=$P[X \le -\infty ,Y \le \infty]$,so this shouldn't be equal to 1,so what is $F_{XY}(-\infty,\infty)$ equal to?

Comment: Inputting $\infty$ or $-\infty$ into a function defined on the real plane is a little bit sketchy, but under most sensible interpretations, yes, $F(-\infty,2) = F(-\infty,\infty) = 0$.

Comment: but why is F(−∞,2)=F(−∞,∞)=0?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{P}(X \leq -\infty, Y \leq \infty) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq - \infty) = 0$ for any real-valued random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ (since $\{X \leq -\infty\} = \{X=-\infty\} = \emptyset$).

Comment: I understand,thankyou